# Orion Context Broker doesn't start

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, contextmanager

I've been working with FIWARE for a school project, I had previously installed Orion and was able to post data to the Context Broker. I rebooted the system since I made some other changes to my set up and Orion has stopped working ever since.

I was trying to start the Context Broker from my command line and its starts. However it doesn't start the Context Broker. The `netstat -tupln` command doesn't display that the port 1026 is in use and the JSON file which had previously posted the data to FIWARE isn't displayed anymore.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-236 config]$ /etc/init.d/contextBroker status
● contextBroker.service - LSB: run contextBroker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since mån 2018-01-01 15:38:39 UTC; 42min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1829 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Memory: 0B

jan 01 15:38:37 ip-172-31-31-236.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting LSB: run contextBroker...
jan 01 15:38:37 ip-172-31-31-236.ap-south-1.compute.internal contextBroker[1829]: Starting...
jan 01 15:38:37 ip-172-31-31-236.ap-south-1.compute.internal contextBroker[1829]: contextBroker is stopped
jan 01 15:38:37 ip-172-31-31-236.ap-south-1.compute.internal su[1834]: (to orion) root on none
jan 01 15:38:37 ip-172-31-31-236.ap-south-1.compute.internal su[1837]: (to orion) root on none
jan 01 15:38:39 ip-172-31-31-236.ap-south-1.compute.internal contextBroker[1829]: Starting contextBroker...                         [  OK  ]
jan 01 15:38:39 ip-172-31-31-236.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started LSB: run contextBroker.

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-236 config]$ sudo netstat -tupln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      900/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      864/master          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      900/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      864/master          
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2353/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2363/docker-proxy   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           546/dhclient        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44244           0.0.0.0:*                           546/dhclient        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           511/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 :::24106                :::*                                546/dhclient        
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                511/chronyd         
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-236 config]$ 

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-236 config]$ curl localhost:1026/version
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:1026; Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked that MongoDB is running ?

have you checked the content of the /tmp/contextBroker.log file?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, The monogoDB seems to be not running, and i get an error when i try to run it.    
time=2018-01-01T19:36:39.310Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[1$.

Comment: If MongoDB is not running it is normal you get Orion log errors about it. Please, ensure first your MongoDB instance is running (check MongoDB official documentation about it if you need) and check it is ok (typically, running the mongo shell with `mongo` command).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured that my MongoDB stopped running as my machine had no space left, i expanded my filesystem and the issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. At my first installation apparently everything went well, but after rebooting the machine the Orion service doesn't start.

MongoDB is running.

```
[rober@localhost ~]$ systemctl status contextBroker.service
● contextBroker.service - LSB: run contextBroker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since vie 2018-08-03 11:53:20 CEST; 23s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1712 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/contextBroker start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ago 03 11:53:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: run contextBroker...
ago 03 11:53:18 localhost.localdomain contextBroker[1712]: contextBroker está detenido
ago 03 11:53:18 localhost.localdomain contextBroker[1712]: Starting...
ago 03 11:53:18 localhost.localdomain su[1718]: (to orion) root on none
ago 03 11:53:20 localhost.localdomain contextBroker[1712]: Starting contextBroker...                         cat: /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid: No existe el fichero o el directorio
ago 03 11:53:20 localhost.localdomain contextBroker[1712]: pidfile not found[FALLÓ]
ago 03 11:53:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: contextBroker.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
ago 03 11:53:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: run contextBroker.
ago 03 11:53:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit contextBroker.service entered failed state.
ago 03 11:53:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: contextBroker.service failed.
```

This is the content of the log file /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.log

```
time=2018-08-03T09:31:10.021Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:32:30.401Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:33:46.508Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:36:13.636Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:36:31.675Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:37:54.942Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:39:01.179Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:40:11.421Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:47:36.258Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
time=2018-08-03T09:53:18.581Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[399]:pidFile | msg=PID File (open '/var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid': No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed and re-installed contextBroker whilst mongo was running, and then everything was working